# Vue - returning the result of a synchronous method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm struggling to return the synchronous results of the method below.

I call the method from a different method:

```
var result = this.getVendor(id)
console.log(result)
```

Here is the fetch method:

```
methods: {
    async getData(id) {
          const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}api/${id}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
            }
          })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              return data;
            });

          await response;
        }
}
```

How do I return the results `response` of the `getData()` function to show in the console?

Comment: I think you want to `return response` instead of `await response`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async functions **Always** return a promise.

You can use the await syntax to return it properly.

```js
    async getData(id) {
          const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}api/${id}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
            }
          })
           const data = await response.json()

           return data
        }
```

You can access the data out of that function anywhere you call it.

```js
let data = null
object.getData(2)
.then(x => {
data = x
})
```

Also if you are going to use async await make sure to use try and catch to handle any errors that come up.

```js
    async getData(id) {
       try {
          const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}api/${id}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
            }
          })
           const data = await response.json()

           return data
        }
      } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
    }
```